# Add Config Transforms not adding all configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config-transform

I'm having an issue with the "Add Config Transforms" option in Visual Studio 2010. I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web project with the following 4 configuration modes defined:

- Debug
- Local
- PreProduction
- Release

When I right click on the web.config and select "Add Config Transforms" only the following two config transforms are added:

- Web.Debug.config
- Web.Release.config

The "PreProduction" and "Local" files do not show up. Is there a setting that I'm missing that would cause these two files to now show up?

Comment: Semi-related ... check out the SlowCheetah VS add-in at ... [visualstudiogallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Verify that the same configurations have been defined for the project and not just the solution.

Comment: This ended up being the issue. Thank you !

Comment: How did you actually go about doing this? Hand edit the proj file?

Comment: @MikeCheel, right click on the solution, select Configuration Manager, modify the configurations for each project.

Comment: Aside from that I had to manually edit the project files and solution files to get everything in sync. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Right Click the solution and open up the configuration manager,

Now in the top box select a new configuration.
The project you are having problems with will be marked Release or Debug.

Click the drop down and select new.

Deselect the checkbox at the bottom, and type in the name of the selected configuration.
use copy values from release.

Close and save,
rinse and repeat.

now right click the main config file and add transforms.